# Closed points of a scheme (locally) of finite type over an algebraically closed field

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

If $X$ is an arbitrary scheme, I can prove that the set $X(k)$ of $k$-valued points is in bijective correspondence with the set $$\{(x,\iota) \, | \, x \in X, \, \iota:\kappa(x) \hookrightarrow k\},$$ where $\kappa(x)$ is the residue field of $x$ on $X$.  (This is the content of Hartshorne, Exercise II.2.7.)  Assuming now that $X$ is (locally?) of finite type over $k$, $\kappa(x)$ becomes a finitely generated $k$-algebra, which is a field, hence (by Zariski's Lemma) is a finite extension of $k$.

1. This seems to imply that, in this case, $X(k)$ bijects with the set $\{x \in X \, | \, \iota:\kappa(x) \to k \mbox{ is an isomorphism}\}$ (such points are $\textit{$k$-rational}$), but $X(k)$ is supposed to be in bijective correspondence with the set of closed points, and the set of closed points merely have the property that $\kappa(x)/k$ is a finite extension.  How do I reconcile this?  In other words, is it true that for $X$ finite type over $k$ algebraically closed, $k$-rational points coincide with closed points?  Certainly, $k$-rational points are closed, but if this is true, how do I show the converse?
2. If $k$ is not algebraically closed, I have seen examples of closed points which are not $k$-rational.  Where have I used the fact that $k$ is algebraically closed?

Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: If $k$ is algebraically closed, then it has no non-trivial finite extensions.

Comment: Oh, right.  That was stupid :(

Comment: At the risk of asking another stupid question, what is wrong with this when $k$ is not algebraically closed?  Ex. II.2.7 works for any field, and Zariski's Lemma doesn't require $k$ to be algebraically closed...

Comment: Zariski's lemma implies that for $X$ a $k$-scheme locally of finite type, $x\in X$ is a closed point if and only if $k(x)/k$ is finite. If $k$ is algebraically closed, this then says that $x$ is a closed point if and only if it is a $k$-point, i.e., the set of $k$-points coincides with the set of closed points.

Comment: There's a small subtlety in the definitions: if $X$ is a scheme over $k$, then a $k$-rational point is a morphism $\operatorname{Spec} k \to X$ such that the composite $\operatorname{Spec} k \to X \to \operatorname{Spec} k$ is the identity. This is necessary to avoid overcounting when $k$ has non-trivial automorphisms. (For instance, there are infinitely many scheme morphisms $\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb{C} \to \operatorname{Spec} \mathbb{C}$!)